(wrong) marker - colors
I am taking my very first steps in tikz and pgfplots.
I use the following packages
%TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

I plot a so called bode-diagram, that is logrithmic. So I wrote the following:
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[
%[...]

I am plotting data  with
    \addplot[blue, mark=*] coordinates {
        (100, 69)
        (200, 57)
%[...]

this is drawing the expexted curve in blue with blue marks
after that I add some marks with
    \addplot[
            scatter,
            only marks,
            mark=x, 
            mark options={scale=1.5},
            ] coordinates {
                (351, 45)
            } node[pos=1,distance=2.5cm, pin=below right:{351 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};
%[....] 

and in this case this marker is drawn in red.
But one other marker, that I add is blue.
I have tried to use
            \addplot[
            scatter,
            only marks,
            mark=x, 
            mark options={scale=1.5, fill=blue},
            ] coordinates {
                (351, 45)
            } node[pos=1,distance=2.5cm, pin= right:{351 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};

but it did not change anything. The cross is still red.
Can anybody halp me to understand, what is wrong with my code?
do you need any further information, to help me out. As I wrote, I am totaly new to this .... and to this forum ....
Here is a compilable extract
\documentclass{article} 
%TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        width=0.7\textwidth, % Breite des Plots
        height=8cm, % Höhe des Plots
        xlabel={$f$[Hz]},
        ylabel={$\varphi\ [^\circ]$},
        xmin=100, xmax=100000, % x-Achse Bereich
        ymin=-90, ymax=90, % y-Achse Bereich
        ytick={-90,-75,...,90},
        grid=both,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
        xtick={100, 1000, 10000}, % Haupttickwerte auf der x-Achse
        minor xtick={200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,
            2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000,
            20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000}, % Minorticks
        ]
        
        %grenzfrequenz
        \addplot[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        mark color=black,
        mark size=3,
        mark=x, 
        ] coordinates {
            (351, 45)
        } node[pos=1,distance=2.5cm, pin= right:{351 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};
        
        %grenzfrequenz
        \addplot[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        mark color=blue,
        mark size=3,
        mark=x, 
        ] coordinates {
            (13023, -45)
        } node[pos=2, pin=left :{13023 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};
        
        
        % Hochpass-Daten
        \addplot[blue, mark=*] coordinates {
            (100, 69)
            (200, 57)
            (500, 31)
            (1000, 14)
            (2000, -0.9)
            (5000, -21)
            (10000, -40)
            (20000, -56)
            (50000, -75)
        };
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Have a nice day

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

As NBur answered, that's related to the built-in scatter-behavior. You most likely can re-style it, but here is may be a simpler way to do it.
Before you end the axis you can put some ordinary Tikz-code like so:
...
        };
        
        % ~~~ just an other option ~~~~~~~~
        \node [teal,anchor=west] at (axis cs: 2000,0) {some remark};
        \draw [teal] (axis cs:5000,-20) circle[radius=3mm] node [anchor=west,xshift=3mm] {re-mark};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

The first line puts a node, using the current axis coordinate system (axis cs:). The rest is just Tikz:

set the color
anchor the node west, i.e. so it appears to continue to the right
it doesn't put an extra symbol, just the text

The second line is similar:

draw something (a circle in this case), again in axis cs
as syntactically a path (=series of actions) starts with \ and ends with ; I can also put a node after that
a shift is needed, this time in non-axis coordinates

I.e. use extra Tikz to put what you need and pgfplots doesn't provide, at least not easily.
BTW: I don't see why you'd need the minor ticks being specified.

\documentclass{article} 
%TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        width=0.7\textwidth, % Breite des Plots
        height=8cm, % Höhe des Plots
        xlabel={$f$[Hz]},
        ylabel={$\varphi\ [^\circ]$},
        xmin=100, xmax=100000, % x-Achse Bereich
        ymin=-90, ymax=90, % y-Achse Bereich
        ytick={-90,-75,...,90},
        grid=both,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
        xtick={100, 1000, 10000}, % Haupttickwerte auf der x-Achse
%        minor xtick={200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,
%            2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000,
%            20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000, 90000}, % Minorticks
        ]
        
        %grenzfrequenz
        \addplot[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        mark color=black,
        mark size=3,
        mark=x, 
        ] coordinates {
            (351, 45)
        } node[pos=1,distance=2.5cm, pin= right:{351 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};
        
        %grenzfrequenz
        \addplot[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        mark color=blue,
        mark size=3,
        mark=x, 
        ] coordinates {
            (13023, -45)
        } node[pos=2, pin=left :{13023 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};
        
        
        % Hochpass-Daten
        \addplot[blue, mark=*] coordinates {
            (100, 69)
            (200, 57)
            (500, 31)
            (1000, 14)
            (2000, -0.9)
            (5000, -21)
            (10000, -40)
            (20000, -56)
            (50000, -75)
        };
        
        % ~~~ just an other option ~~~~~~~~
        \node [teal,anchor=west] at (axis cs: 2000,0) {some remark};
        \draw [teal] (axis cs:5000,-20) circle[radius=3mm] node [anchor=west,xshift=3mm] {re-mark};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

P.S.:
Within pgfplots please find predefined markers in Ch. "4.7 Markers, Linestyles, (Background) Colors and Colormaps" of its manual. You'll need them e.g. to overwrite styles of dedicated points, e.g. to highlight them visually, like a triangle amongst dots.
Within Tikz please find predefined shapes in "71.2 Predefined Shapes". These would be useful to, e.g. replace my circle, or to emphasize some label text etc.
You can access both manuals online via https://tikz.dev/ , but searching is a bit more limited than in the pdf versions (find them at ctan.org) .
If you just want to use symbols from a special font, e.g. to put them next to a marker pgfplots placed, use a Tikz-node, as in my example, and put that symbol as text. To do so, find a comprehensive list here . As an example, dingbat's phone symbol may or may not fit your diagram ...

This is due to scatter:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{semilogxaxis}
    \addplot[blue, mark=*] coordinates { (100, 69) (200, 57)};
    \addplot[ scatter, only marks, mark=x, mark options={scale=1.5}, ] coordinates { (200, 10) (351, 45) } node[pos=1,distance=2.5cm, pin=below right:{351 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};
    \addplot[ only marks, mark=oplus, mark options={scale=1.5}, cyan] coordinates { (400, 10) (551, 45) } node[pos=1,distance=2.5cm, pin=below right:{351 Hz (Grenzfrequenz)}] {};
  \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



scatter colors the markers depending on the y-value from blue (lowest) to red (highest)
